# printing specific elements of an arraylist

Tags: java

This is a blood transfusion game. I have 2 array lists with donors names and blood type and recipients names and blood type. The program will ask the participants to enter their name and blood type and display a message with who matched.

The code below is the algorithm Im using so at the end it will say "A+ matched with A-"(for example). However I also want the program to display their names for example " John : A+ matched with Ashley : A-"

How do I do this?

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < donorsList.size(); i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < recipientsList.size();j++)
        {
            if (donorsList.get(i).contains("A-") && recipientsList.get(j).contains("O+"))
            {
                System.out.println( donorsList.get(i) + " MATCHED WITH " + recipientsList.get(j));
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where do you store the participants names? It looks like you are using list of Strings or do you have a custom class?

Comment: Yes, exactly what Eritrean says. You seem to have your blood types stored as `String`s within your `donorsList`. This makes your `donorsList` not a donors list, but rather just a blood types list of all of your donors. Java is an object-oriented language. You should create a class `Donor` with as methods `getName()` and `getBloodType()`. Then you can match the blood type of the donor with `donorsList.get(i).getBloodType()`.

Comment: @MCEmperor all the names and blood types are stored in the same list, can you give me and example of what you mean

Comment: @MCEmperor The program asks the donors for full name and blood type and stores both in one arraylist then the same process happens with the recipients and their names and blood type are stored in another arraylist

Comment: Well, you should then show us how you are adding them. Also, it doesn't make sense to add both donor names into one list. Again, you should create a class as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lists of Pair<String, String> (I suppose you are using now a list of lists) where in a pair the key is the donor/recipient name and the value is the blood type. Then:

```
    if (donorsList.get(i).getValue().equals("A-") && recipientsList.get(j).getValue().equals("0+")) {
       System.out.println( donorsList.get(i).getKey() + " MATCHED WITH " + recipientsList.get(j).getKey());
    }
```